# Is it secure to use sql as parameter in private function?

Tags: php, sql, oop

I do also validate `$type`, and use `get/set`.

```
private function somfunc($sql) {
    // query and return result set as an array
}

private function mytype($type) {
    switch ($type)
    case topic: $sql="......";
    return sql;
}

public function display($type) {
    // switch case to require template
    // call somefunc and mytype here
}
```

If it's not secure, how do I improve my code?

Comment: Use parameters / PDO.

Comment: No, it's not secure.

see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @MLeblanc: Why isn't this secure? You can still use prepared statements with this code. OP: you probably want to `return $sql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it secure to use sql as parameter in private function?

The two things are not connected. It's not like using sql as parameter in public function is any safer. The visibility / access of a function does not impact on the safety of SQL. [Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) do.